# Страница не проходит W3C validator

Tags: валидация

Using Direct Input mode: UTF-8 character encoding assumed

Unlike the “by URI” and “by File Upload” modes, the “Direct Input” mode of the validator provides validated content in the form of characters pasted or typed in the validator's form field. This will automatically make the data UTF-8, and therefore the validator does not need to determine the character encoding of your document, and will ignore any charset information specified.

If you notice a discrepancy in detected character encoding between the “Direct Input” mode and other validator modes, this is likely to be the reason. It is neither a bug in the validator, nor in your document.

Comment: и..? где суть вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

Сохраните файл и дайте валидатору ссылку на файл для проверки.